# left join to differentiate between no-exist and row not matching where condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using a `left join`, I'm trying to find which @Er.id does exist, or does not match @Si.id. I know this can be done many ways (`cte` for example), but I'm interested in using a `left join` while checking for null in the `where` statement.

Here's my script:

```
DECLARE @Er table (  ID varchar(20)  )

insert into @Er 
select '001' union 
select '028' union 
select '294' union 
select '352' union 
select '358' union 
select '500'

DECLARE @Si table 
(
    ID varchar(20),
    IsValid varchar(1)
)

insert into @Si 
select '001', 'N' union 
select '028', 'Y' union 
select '294', 'Y' union 
select '352', 'Y' union 
select '358', 'Y' 

select Er.id as 'Er', Si.id as 'Si' from 
@Er er left join @Si si on
Er.id = Si.id
and si.isvalid = 'Y'
where
Si.id is null
```

By using the `On clause`, the result will display two rows: 001 and 500. 001 matches (but does not meet `on si.isvalid = 'Y'`) and 500 doesn't exist on @Si. Issue is I can't distinguish between these two rows.

By using the `Where clause` (where si.isvalid = 'Y'), it automatically converts to an `inner join`, so nothing is displayed.

By using this syntax or a similar syntax, is there a way to distinguish one from the other? Something like this:

```
Er    Si     IsValid
001   NULL   N
500   NULL
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two left joins, but I think `exists` is better:

```
select Er.id as Er, Si.id as Si,
       (case when exists (select 1 from @Si si where si.id = er.id) then 'N'
        end) as IsValid
from @Er er left join
     @Si si
     on Er.id = Si.id and si.isvalid = 'Y'
where Si.id is null;
```

If you are expecting at one matching row in `@Si`, then I think the following has the desired logic:

```
select Er.id as Er, NULL as Si, si.IsValid
from @Er er left join
     @Si si
     on Er.id = Si.id and si.isvalid = 'Y'
where Si.id is null or si.isvalid <> 'Y';
```